Spring 6.x MVC Exception
I'm trying to build a simple Spring 6 MVC app and regardless whether I setup it up as XML only or use a WebInitializer class I keep getting a NoSuchMethod Error when starting in Tomcat 10 (not new to Spring - have several Spring 5 apps in production).  Below are the jars in the web app (only essential) and then a stacktrace:

aspectjweaver-1.9.22.jar
jakarta.servlet-api-6.1.0-M2.jar
jakarta.servlet.jsp-api-4.0.0-M2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
micrometer-commons-1.12.5.jar
micrometer-observation-1.12.5.jar
spring-aop-6.1.6.jar
spring-aspects-6.1.6.jar
spring-beans-6.1.6.jar
spring-context-6.1.6.jar
spring-core-6.0.10.jar
spring-expression-6.1.6.jar
spring-jcl-6.0.10.jar
spring-web-6.1.6.jar
spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar
23-May-2024 12:35:12.626 INFO [main] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
23-May-2024 12:35:12.664 SEVERE [main] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.ThreadLocal org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal.withInitial(java.lang.String, java.util.function.Supplier)'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:139
As noted, I have tried both an xml only approach and WebInitializer (various flavors - xml, annotation, etc...).  Same problem.

Are you using at least Java 17 and have you tried to build the skeleton of you application via https://start.spring.io/? I think your issue is either with the wrong version of Java or a dependency mismatch.

You could post your Pom.xml or grade file also to give some idea of your dependencies.
